# Offset doesn't return anything but undefined for absolute positioned element

Tags: jquery

I'm simply trying to return an offset for a `<ul>`

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    console.log($('#rooms').offset.top);
}
```

**CSS:**

```
#rooms {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 300px;
height: 690px;
padding: 40px;
overflow: auto;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
&::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
}
```

However, the console only outputs `undefined`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) is a function.

Use

```
console.log($('#rooms').offset().top);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call it like:

```
$('#rooms').offset().top
```